# jquery get request not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery get request that isn't working. I don't understand why, because my research leads me to believe this should work, but it doesn't....

```
$.get('http://www.triadbarspecials.com/ws/index.php', function(html){
 $('#page').append(html); 
});
```

`#page` is a div. I own the domain, and am calling from that domain, so that's not a problem. I really can't imagine what is going on here. This should insert HTML directly into the div and work magically, but I'm obviously no Houdini

[Here's a link to the page that makes the request](http://www.triadbarspecials.com/app/test.html)

Comment: We aren't either. Do you have any URL to test it? What does your error console say?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the call using something like Fiddler?

Comment: Owning the domain is not enough, is this code from the same domain?

Comment: Saying it's not working isn't enough. What **does** happen? If nothing visible happens, have you checked the following: You have no Javascript errors. The request is actually being sent. You aren't getting any server-side errors. A success response actually comes back. If something visible happens, tell us what.

Comment: The URL to test is in the get request. It doesn't work in jsFiddle. This code is from the same domain. @AnthonyGist There is a js error, looks like this: GET http://www.triadbarspecials.com/ws/index.php 200 OK x 285ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't work because its against the Same Origin Policy:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
```

Ways it that work:

- pull data in an json Object using jsonp
- Being on the same domain and referencing it like `/ws/index.php` if your request is being done from the same domain.

Comment: "I own the domain, and **am calling from that domain**, so that's not a problem." Assuming that statement from the question is true, that's not the answer.

Comment: He could use a Proxy class serverside to retrieve these data

Comment: I tried referencing like you said and it works. I guess maybe having the entire URL in the request makes the domain think it's coming from an outside source? Is that what's going on?

Comment: If you reference it with the entire URL the request thinks of hmm maybe this is not my actual domain, that's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here, if you call from the exact same domain it should work :
http://jsfiddle.net/FVzEL/

So that's stupid questions but :

- Is your div using `id="page"` ?
- Is your div visible ? Did you try replacing html by a "test string" ?
- Are you calling from the exact same domain ? (You said so in the answer)
- Did you check if the request was done ?
- Did you check any HTTP error from the response ?
- Did you check the response message ?

Comment: top 4 questions, yes. there's a js error that I don't understand, but it basically says how long the request took, so I'm wondering if it times out or something. There is no repsonse message

Comment: You may want to give us the URL where you use that code so we can check the request/response info ourselves.

Comment: [here's the link](http://www.triadbarspecials.com/ws/test/html)   I'll add it to my question as well

Comment: FYI works pretty well with FF and chrome but not IE and looking at the request IE receive the data, so it may be a CSS problem. No problem with your JQuery code

Comment: Guess you should have told it was jquery for mobile, there may be some restriction I don't know.